# When did I last visit the reputation tab?

Tags: feature-request, reputation, reputation-history

*Oh this is nice. I gained quite a lot of points since I last visited my reputation tab.*

*I wonder when was it that I last visited it?*

*Let me hover over it*...

[image]

*Hmm, not much helpful. So, what about here?*

[image]

*Aarrrggh, neither. ..*

*checks the page and other tabs for the third time*  *Nothing*

Comment: If you actually visit your reputation tab, then the new entries will be highlighted (i.e. entries which are new since the last time you viewed the tab will have a different background color). I don't recall if the highlighting remains if you need to view more than the first tab. With not having visited for 6.5k worth of rep, it's quite likely that there's more than one page of new entries, which may make it difficult to determine when that demarcation was. However, you should be able to look in your browser history, if you don't clear it, to find the last time you visited your reputation page.

Comment: Your reputation tab is at [`https://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=reputation`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=reputation).

Answer (score 4):

Your rep audit, https://stackoverflow.com/reputation ([more info](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43004/how-do-i-audit-my-reputation)), lists your accumulated reputation at the end of each day. You can use this to find out when you last visited your reputation tab.

Find your exact rep gain on the tab itself:

[image: My reputation tab showing that I've gained 245358 rep since my last visit]

Subtract this number from your current total, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> your way through that page to that number (or thereabouts).

Due to rep recalcs that the system runs from time to time you won't always arrive at the exact day of your last visit, but you'll get pretty close — I'd say the margin of error ranges from a day to a week depending on how long you've been active on the site and how much your reputation changes over time.

In my case, taking into account all recalcs I was sitting at an estimated 375511 rep since the last time I ever clicked on that thing. Apparently I haven't clicked it in over 4 and a half years:

```
-- 2016-08-11 rep +199  = 375341    
 2  38910053 (10)
 2  38910053 (10)
 2   3654309 (10)
 2   5324433 (10)
 2   8588532 (10)
 2   5002991 (10)
 2   8539107 (10)
 2   6072011 (10)
 2   8303507 (10)
 2  10450263 (10)
 2   5904891 (10)
 2   5839561 (10)
 2   3772305 (10)
 2   5664791 (10)
 2  38910053 (10)
 1  38910053 (15)
 2   4549183 (10)
 2   4793227 (10)
 2   3052724 (10)
 2   6479033 (10)
 2   4505130 [10]
 2   4325107 [0]
 2   2918716 [0]
 2  16080147 [0]
 2   8849575 [0]
-- 2016-08-12 rep +215  = 375556
```

Heck, I haven't even clicked on the achievements icon in my top bar in a while either:

[image: My achievements icon showing that I've gained 35151 rep since the last time I opened it]

I don't even remember why I stopped visiting my rep tab. I guess I just got lazy. My activity on the site was already starting its decline around that time (before taking a nosedive a couple of years later) and I wouldn't be surprised if I was way past caring about my individual rep gains by then, since the vast majority of it would simply have been from my thousands of existing answers over the years (see those 7- and 8-digit numbers? those are all post IDs. that I have 7-digit post IDs as low as [under 3 million](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2918707) shows you their age).

Comment: nice  Although it is a nice feature, this is not the solution I was hoping for, but nice anyway. Thank you.

Comment: @Qwerty: In fairness, hardly anyone actually cares when they last checked and most people don't go long enough without opening the rep tab that they couldn't just check their browser history for their last visit date. So it's not exactly a use case you'd actively design for.

Comment: I thought I was a notorious/obsessive non-achievement clicker ...

Comment: This is a nice workaround. Only it doesn't account for downvotes on Answers. In your case it'll sure take a while, but in mine not so much. Every time I downvote an Answer it will subtract one from the green bubble. Even if the Answer is deleted, it seems to not show up again by getting re-added to the bubble. When I've downvoted enough Answers, the bubble seem to just disappear.

Comment: @Scratte - a new bug report for the behaviour you mention: [The counter on the Reputation tab does not reflect the net change in reputation since it was last visited](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/406093/1364007)

Comment: @WaiHaLee Thank you for that bug-report. I didn't recall that it only affects deletions on the same UTC date. I must have been more diligent back then :)

Comment: @BoltClock I beg to differ. Nowadays, every site will tell you when was it you did this or that. Anyway, when rendering the accumulated points, I bet that the system knows the date so there is no reason to not to add that to the tooltip.